# Am I Using Assumption Correctly?

Tags: integral-equations

I am trying to solve a problem that has $r > r_c=\frac{a_0*l(l+1)}{2}$ and to solve this integral I am trying to use the Assumption in my integral. I've defined $r_c$ earlier in the code as the above expression.

`Integrate[P[r],{r, rc, Infinity}, Assumptions->r>rc]`

Though I don't think it's working because it still diverges where the textbook says it should converge. If I'm using this incorrectly, or there's a better function to use, I'd greatly appreciate being pointed in the correct direction.

Here is an attempt to paste the actual code using a tutorial I found on here. It certainly doesn't look clean though. This should converge for $l>0$, but only does it for $l=0$.

```
\[Mu] = 4.131; 
\[Gamma] = 6 - \[Mu]; 
l = 1; 
Subscript[a, 0] = 5.27/10^11; 
Subscript[r, c] = (Subscript[a, 0]*l*(l + 1))/2
P[r_] := (Subscript[a, 0]/(\[Gamma]^2*Sqrt[Gamma[\[Gamma] + l + 1]*Gamma[\[Gamma] - l]]))*(\[Gamma]/E^(r/(Subscript[a, 0]*\[Gamma])))*
    ((2*r)/(Subscript[a, 0]*\[Gamma]))^(l + 1)*HypergeometricU[1 + l - \[Gamma], 2 + 2*l, (2*r)/(Subscript[a, 0]*\[Gamma])]; 
Integrate[P[r]^2, {r, Subscript[r, c], Infinity}, Assumptions -> r > Subscript[r, c]]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include details for `P[r]`. The idea is that forum participants should be able to copy and paste your Mathematica code into their own notebooks and study the difficulties you are facing. The solutions offered, as a consequence, become more focused. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed I am trying to copy and paste that over, but it isn't working. It is messing up things like square roots and variables like $\gamma$. I tried highlighting and exporting it as all available options but none printed cleanly into stack exchange. Is there an easy way to do that so I don't have to do it by hand and ensure I don't make a mistake? Edit: I added the code with steps from [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site).

Comment: @Syed I added it to the question.

Comment: Is there a `Gamma` and a Greek $\gamma$? Are these separate variables?

Comment: $Gamma$ is the Gamma Function and there is a variable $\gamma$. The two Gamma functions are inside of the square root.

Comment: `Plot[P[r]^2, {r, Subscript[r, c], 1 } ]` indicates `P[r]^2==0`!

Comment: This `rc=Subscript[r,c]; With[{scale=rc}, scale*NIntegrate[P[scale*s]^2,{s,rc/scale,Infinity}]]` works and gives `1.48729*10^-31`. The value of `scale` has no influence on the result, you get the same answer if you use `scale=2*rc` for example, it simply amounts to a scaling of the integration variable. In principle you can also use `scale=1`, equivalent to what you did, but it does not work, probably `NIntegrate` has trouble detecting the length scale at which the integrand lives, which is very small in your case, around $r_c = 5.27 \cdot 10^{-11}$.

Comment: @user293787 That seems to be working! Can you make an answer with your explanation so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks for that! I thought about plotting it beforehand but totally forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main contribution to this integral come from a very small interval whose size is on the order of $r_c = 5.27 \cdot 10^{-11}$. It seems that `NIntegrate` has trouble detecting that that is the right length scale, and therefore OP does not obtain a useful result.

A workaround solution is to manually scale the integral as in

```
rc=Subscript[r,c];
With[{scale=rc},
  scale*NIntegrate[P[scale*s]^2,{s,rc/scale,Infinity}]]
(* 1.48729*10^-31 *)
```

The value of `scale` has no influence on the result, one obtains the same answer using `scale=2*rc` for example, it simply amounts to a scaling of the integration variable. In principle one can also use `scale=1`, which is equivalent to what OP did, but it does not work, for the reasons mentioned at the beginning.